# how can I use mahout results?

Tags: mahout, recommendation-engine, mahout-recommender

I want build a basic movie recommender system. I searched and I found apache mahout.I used some method but I don't know how can I use those results.

```
import java.io.File;
import java.io.IOException;
import org.apache.mahout.cf.taste.common.TasteException;
import org.apache.mahout.cf.taste.eval.RecommenderBuilder;
import org.apache.mahout.cf.taste.eval.RecommenderEvaluator;
import org.apache.mahout.cf.taste.impl.eval.RMSRecommenderEvaluator;
import org.apache.mahout.cf.taste.impl.model.file.FileDataModel;
import org.apache.mahout.cf.taste.impl.neighborhood.NearestNUserNeighborhood;
import org.apache.mahout.cf.taste.impl.recommender.GenericUserBasedRecommender;
import org.apache.mahout.cf.taste.impl.similarity.PearsonCorrelationSimilarity;
import org.apache.mahout.cf.taste.impl.similarity.TanimotoCoefficientSimilarity;
import org.apache.mahout.cf.taste.model.DataModel;
import org.apache.mahout.cf.taste.neighborhood.UserNeighborhood;
import org.apache.mahout.cf.taste.recommender.Recommender;
import org.apache.mahout.cf.taste.similarity.UserSimilarity;

public class error {

  public  static double evaluate(DataModel model){
    RecommenderEvaluator evaluator = new RMSRecommenderEvaluator();
    RecommenderBuilder builder = new RecommenderBuilder() {

        @Override
        public Recommender buildRecommender(DataModel model) throws TasteException {
            UserSimilarity similarity = new TanimotoCoefficientSimilarity(model);
            UserNeighborhood neighborhood = new NearestNUserNeighborhood(50, similarity,        model);
            return new GenericUserBasedRecommender(model, neighborhood, similarity);
        }
    };

    double score = 0;
    try {

        score = evaluator.evaluate(builder, null, model, 0.7, 1.0);
    } catch (TasteException e) {
    }
    System.out.println(score);
    return score;
}
public static void main(String[] args) throws IOException, TasteException {
     DataModel model = new FileDataModel(new File("u1.base"));
    evaluate(model);
}

}
```

and results like this

> Şub 03, 2014 2:06:44 PM org.slf4j.impl.JCLLoggerAdapter info INFO:
>   Creating FileDataModel for file u1.base Şub 03, 2014 2:06:44 PM
>   org.slf4j.impl.JCLLoggerAdapter info INFO: Reading file info... Şub
>   03, 2014 2:06:44 PM org.slf4j.impl.JCLLoggerAdapter info INFO: Read
>   lines: 80000 Şub 03, 2014 2:06:44 PM org.slf4j.impl.JCLLoggerAdapter
>   info INFO: Processed 943 users Şub 03, 2014 2:06:44 PM
>   org.slf4j.impl.JCLLoggerAdapter info INFO: Beginning evaluation using
>   0.7 of FileDataModel[dataFile:C:\Users\HydrojaN\Documents\NetBeansProjects\JavaApplication1\u1.base]
>   Şub 03, 2014 2:06:44 PM org.slf4j.impl.JCLLoggerAdapter info INFO:
>   Processed 943 users Şub 03, 2014 2:06:44 PM
>   org.slf4j.impl.JCLLoggerAdapter info INFO: Beginning evaluation of 941
>   users Şub 03, 2014 2:06:44 PM org.slf4j.impl.JCLLoggerAdapter info
>   INFO: Starting timing of 941 tasks in 4 threads Şub 03, 2014 2:06:45
>   PM org.slf4j.impl.JCLLoggerAdapter info INFO: Average time per
>   recommendation: 193ms Şub 03, 2014 2:06:45 PM
>   org.slf4j.impl.JCLLoggerAdapter info INFO: Approximate memory used:
>   86MB / 276MB Şub 03, 2014 2:06:45 PM org.slf4j.impl.JCLLoggerAdapter
>   info INFO: Unable to recommend in 29 cases

```
1.0364950141746245
```

Şub 03, 2014 2:07:49 PM org.slf4j.impl.JCLLoggerAdapter info
INFO: Evaluation result: 1.0364950141746245
BUILD SUCCESSFUL (total time: 1 minute 5 seconds)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Do you want to do evaluation or you want to use the recommender. With the above code you are evaluating the efficiency of the algorithm (similarity measure together with the recommender algorithm) against your data set. If you want to use the results the recommender is producing you can use the following simple code:

```
class RecommenderExample { 

      public static void main(String[] args) throws Exception {
            DataModel model = new FileDataModel (new File("u1.base"));

            UserSimilarity similarity = new TanimotoCoefficientSimilarity(model);
            UserNeighborhood neighborhood = new NearestNUserNeighborhood(50, similarity,        model);

            Recommender recommender = new GenericUserBasedRecommender (model, neighborhood, similarity);

            List<RecommendedItem> recommendations = recommender.recommend(1, 1);

            //Print the results
            for (RecommendedItem recommendation : recommendations) {
                 System.out.println(recommendation);
             }
    }
}
```

In any case you need evaluation to choose the best algorithm, but at the end if you want to recommend items to the user you can use similar code like this one.

You can find more about Mahout in the book [Mahout in Action](http://manning.com/owen/).

Answer (score 0):

It will always be easier to get Mahout answers on the Mahout mailing lists.

That said, you don't need to do very much with the Mahout API itself to build a simple recommender.  What I suggest is that you use the search abuse style of recommender.  In this method, you run a Mahout job to analyze logs and then import those logs into a search engine like Solr or Elastic Search.  This search engine then acts as a recommender.

See http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=fWR1T2pY08Y for some more details